# Find date after a given weeks(months) in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime

I want to find a date after a give weeks(months).
For example, I want to find the date after 2 week from today or find the date after 4 month from today.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you want like ?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
```

to get the date 2 weeks from now

or

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4)
```

to get the date 4 months from now

**NB:** This has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  DateTime is part of the .NET BCL.

Answer (score 2):

Two weeks after today:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2*7)
```

Four months after today:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(4)
```

Use *DateTime.Date* if you want only the date without current time (as in the sample).

Comment: Thanks :)  2*7 will be optimised by compiler but for a human reading the code is a bit easier to understand, especially if there should be something like 13 weeks